# PHP & MySQL date

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert in a field of type "timestamp" in MySQL database "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" and its 2012-2-26 10:04:34 AM in my local are and its the time on my pc
but the thing is that I find it 2012-02-26 02:04:34 in my database
everytime I insert I find different values from my local time
and aslo if I do

```
echo strtotime('now');
```

it prints the same value "2012-02-26 02:04:34"

how can I fix , knowing that I am working on a schedule needs to perform operations on a certain time

Comment: Your server is running at another timezone. Set it in php to your timezone with http://www.php.net/date_default_timezone_set and use the time taken by php. For MySQL read this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: What is the query you are using for the data entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like problem with time zones. Check them in `php.ini`. Or as suggested my Cheery on the comment, use <sup>[*[docs here]*](http://www.php.net/date_default_timezone_set)</sup>

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
?>
```

However, You should make sure you are using correct methods to input the date and time in the database. There are two ways to do so.

1. **MYSQL:** Use [`NOW()`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_now.asp) Function

   ```
   INSERT INTO table VALUES( data = '$data', date = now());
   ```
2. **PHP:** Use [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) Function

   ```
   $query = "INSERT INTO table VALUES( data = '$data', date = '".time()."');"
   ```

Comment: thanks alot , I am using date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Minsk');
since I am GMT+2 and its 10:27
echo date("Y-m-d G:i:s"); // prints 11:27 is it a wrong time zone for me ??

Comment: On that case, the credit goes to @Cheery. I am glad, it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sql to set your current timezone.

```
    set time_zone = <your timezone>;
```

eg.

```
    set time_zone = 'Asia/Calcutta'
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to use MySQL's `NOW()` function in your SQL query, to get the current time while executing the query.

Comment: Please, try to answer properly. What do you mean by `thingie`?